# Palantir Foundry forbids connection to external web service

Tags: palantir-foundry

I want to query weather information using the `meteostat` library. When doing so, however, Palantir Foundry forbids requests to the external web service. The code example below fails with the error message `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>`. What can I do about this?

```py
from dateutil import parser as dateparser
from meteostat import Point, Hourly


loc = Point(47.00823, 4.849133)
start = dateparser.parse("2021-09-20 13:14:36+00:00")
end = dateparser.parse("2021-09-20 14:14:36+00:00")

# Queries information from an external source (fails!)
data = Hourly(loc, start, end)
data = data.fetch()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code repositories by default have all the external communication disabled. To enable it you can follow this documentation: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/external-transforms/

Comment: Okay, thanks! So I would need to define an egress policy?

Comment: Indeed that's the way !

Comment: Sorry, I do not have enough reputation to upvote yet, but thanks a lot!